# A is compact if and only if A is finite

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space. Let $ A \subset X$ have the property that $\exists \epsilon >0$ : $\forall a, b \in A$: $d(a,b) \geq \epsilon$ with $a \neq b$.  Prove $A$ is compact if and only if $A$ is finite.

Start of proof:

Assume $A$ is compact and infinite. Since for any two elements $a,b$ of A we have $d(a,b) \geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$, each element of $A$ is an open set. 
Let $A = \{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Then $\mathcal{C} = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ is an open cover. Since $A$ is compact, $\mathcal{C}$ must have a finite sub cover. But this can only happen if there are finitely many $a_i$. So the assumption that $A$ is infinite is false.

Now assume $A$ is finite. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an arbitrary open cover of $A$. Let each element of $A$ correspond to exactly one open set in open cover $\mathcal{C}$ that contains it. Since $A$ is finite, we have a finite sub cover. Thus $A$ is compact.

Does this proof work? Any hints or advice on how to complete this proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you write the quantifier $\forall a,b\in A$ at the end of the sentence, when an essential point is whether it comes before of after the other quatifier $\exists \epsilon$? Writing instead $\exists \epsilon>0:~\forall a,b\in  A:~d(a,b)\geq0$ would be both more correct and easier to read.

Comment: Closed and bounded does _not_ imply compact in a general metric space!

Comment: To be nit-picky, the only subset of $X$ that satisfies that hypothesis (as it's written) is $\emptyset$ (since $ \forall a\in X,\ \ d(a,a)=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is compact and infinite..

We can get a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that no two $a_n$ are same..

As $A$ is compact, this $(a_n)$ has a convergent sub sequence..

Can you get a convergent sub sequence in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint: Your condition that there is some lower bound on the distance between elements in $A$ implies that the points in $A$ (with the subspace topology) are each open. Now show that a discrete space is finite iff it is compact. (Using the open covering definition.)